# How to use HTML inside ZF2 FlashMessenger

Tags: zend-framework2, flashmessenger

I want to use an `<a>` inside a flashMessenger message.

For example:
In my website I have some blog posts, and when I delete one of them, I want to show a message like:
"`Success! <a>Undo</a>`"

My code:

```
  $restore = $this->url()->fromRoute('news/restore', array('id' => $id));
  $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage("Success. <a href='$restore'>Undo</a>");
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('news');
```

But It doesn't work when I put that `<a>` inside the message.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way it worked for me:

```
<?php if($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()): ?>

    <div class="alert alert-info flash-messenger">
        <?=$this->flashMessenger()->setAutoEscape(false)->render(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

By default the autoEscape property is set to `true`

Factory? Maybe?

source:

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/FlashMessenger.php

Comment: Is there a way to do this with ZF1?

Comment: @Brian I think that in ZF1 the strings are not escaped at all.